# How can I remove Virtualbox and VMware work station from linux?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, 22.04, vmware

I am user of Ubuntu 22.04 and have had Virtualbox and VMware work station on my system, but  as a reason I want remove them. The point is that in my applications list both icons are there, but when I want remove them either by command line or Graphically I can't find them. I use following command on terminal to see my apps:

```
sudo dpkg --list
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove vmware with `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation`.

From vmware [docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-05E4C876-F32C-49D2-82B4-8C759691E7F5.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works